# Profit maximization; how to derive

Tags: optimization, profit-maximization

[image]

Can someone expalin me the math process step by step behind this? I haven't been able to figure it out and I cannot find anything in google

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find anything in google

The keywords you are looking for are "local extrema" or "local maximum" and "optimization". Using these my first result was quite good, [a chapter of an online book from the Department of Mathematics at Whitman College](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section06.01.html).